# Django many to many relationship. Connect two tables using id number different then ID(primary key)

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql

I trying to build a relational database which consists of two tables. 
I didn't have any problems with building a database with many to many relationships. but the problem starts when I'm changing the primary key

I need to input old data that I have to a db. In one of the lists I would have a list of clients and in the other list of entities. Clients should have relationships with several entities.

For example:

```
Client A:
Entity 1
Entity 2
Entity 3

Client B:
Entity 6
Entity 1
Entity 2
Entity 8

Table of Clients:
Client A (identification number: 6582395)
Client B (identification number: 7866732)

Table of Entities:
Entity 1 (identification number: 6582395)
Entity 1 (identification number: 7866732)
Entity 2 (identification number: 6582395)
Entity 2 (identification number: 7866732)
Entity 3 (identification number: 6582395)
Entity 6 (identification number: 7866732)
Entity 8 (identification number: 7866732)
```

Entities would be reused to several clients.

The trick is that I have old data, in which I can only compare each list using 
"identification number:".
I don't know how to do it. if I go with a primary key then I cannot have Entities with duplicated identification numbers (which is the only way for me to create a relationship with between two lists.

```
class Entities(models.Model):
    e_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    e_country = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    e_SAP_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=False, unique=False)
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)

class Clients(models.Model):
    client_name = models.CharField('Clients full legal name', max_length=255)
    SAP_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    c_country = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField()
    c_structure = models.ManyToManyField(Entities, related_name='e_SAP_ids', blank=True)
    c_structure_string = models.TextField(default='')
```

As you can see I'm trying to set the e_SAP_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=False, unique=False) with unique=False but it not allows me. I cannot create several entities with the same Identification number.

Please help me. I don't know what to do with this...

Thank you in advance

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by it doesn't allow you. For a start I'm not sure why you've specified `primary_key=False`, that's the default of course. A primary key cannot be non-unique but a normal integer field can be.

Answer (score 0):

If you are integrating an existing database you can:

Generate your models inspecting the old database.

```
$ python manage.py inspectdb
```

or

```
$ python manage.py inspectdb > models.py
```

This would be the steps:

1. Configure your Django project to use the old DB.
2. Generate models like shown above.
3. Migrate or fake migrations if as you need.

Reference: [Integrating Django with a legacy database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/legacy-databases/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're importing the data (rather than connecting to the old db), then your import script can create the relationship on-the-fly for each entity relationship it imports.

I would not store the `e_SAP_id` on `Entity` at all (remove that field from your `Entity` model, since that's the id of the `Client`. Just add the relationship:

```
for old_entity in old_entities: 
    c = Client.objects.get(SAP_id=old_entity['identification_number'])
    e = Entity.objects.get(name=old_entity['name'])  # if unique  
    # or maybe you should create the entity here:
    # e = Entity.objects.get_or_create(name=old_entity['name'], defaults={'country': old_entity['country']})
    c.entities.add(e)

# note: assumption is "entities" field on Client
class Client(Model):

     ...
     entities = models.ManyToManyField(Entities, related_name='clients', blank=True)
```